# How are sites made that lack file extensions?

Tags: html, directory, subdirectory

So I am used to coding sites in asp.net with master pages and .aspx file extensions. However more and more I see sites that the lack file extensions completely. Example: www.example.com/subpage1. Because my non-work computer is a mac, and asp.net is pretty much out, I thought my next freelance project would be a good place to start.

I thought I would give the pages .php extensions as the php includes feature is pretty easy to implement. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

URLs do not represent files.  They are just that, resource locations.

The web server decides how to interpret the location into a resource, and sends back a response.

Apache, a common web server used with PHP, can use the `mod_rewrite` module to configure paths with regular expressions and map them to different local resources (such as PHP files).

Answer (score 1):

These are called Search Engine Optimized (SEO) URLs (sometimes called Search Engine Friendly URLs). It sounds like first maybe you need a good basic understanding of PHP and other general programming basics.

Here are some links to get you on the right track:

- [URL Rewriting for Beginners](http://www.addedbytes.com/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)
- [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)
- [PHP Tutorial for Beginners](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/)

I'm sure others can provide some more useful links. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Read the links provided by bdares and tptcat above. Here are some I've used...

These two gives each person an URL like `example.com/~person/` and `example.com/~person/gallery`:

```
RewriteRule   ^~([^/]+)/?$ artist.php?name=$1
RewriteRule   ^~([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ artist.php?name=$1&gallery=$2
```

These three allow the View/Add/Delete links appear like `example.com/View/Some_group/~person/55/`, `example.com/Add/Some_group/~person/55/`, `example.com/Delete/Some_group/~person/55/`:

```
RewriteRule   ^View/([a-z0-9]+)_group/~([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ details.php?a=$2&p=$3&c=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule    ^Add/([a-z0-9]+)_group/~([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ details.php?a=$2&p=$3&c=$1&add=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^Remove/([a-z0-9]+)_group/~([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ details.php?a=$2&p=$3&c=$1&remove=1 [NC]
```

and so on...